# How do I make my friend Notable?

Tags: fallen-london

I have a friend who's standing is ripe for improvement.

I've heard rumors that, if given the opportunity, I could bequeath some of my own Notability to launch their ascendency.

But I can't find such an opportunity, and I'm now worried that it doesn't really exist.

Can you still gift someone their first point of Notability?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to draw an ["A visit from Slowcake's Amanuensis"](http://fallenlondon.wikia.com/wiki/A_visit_from_Slowcake's_Amanuensis) card. Amongst its options is "Recommend an unknown acquaintance", which is unlocked when you have at least 2 Notability. It's in game description is:

> This will transfer a single point of Notability from you to a friend with zero Notability, allowing them to summon the Amanuensis.

Unfortunately the Amanuensis card is infrequent. If your Making Waves is high enough to reach the next Notability level, you can still draw it from the "Attend to matters of society and scandal" option in your lodging.

Comment: Hmm, is this wiki page still accurate? I have 5 notability and have now drawn the card, but I don't see the "Recommend an unknown acquaintance" option. Is there something else that would hide this option?

Comment: @RedRiderX I assumed it was because I lack an eligible friend, but now you mentioned it, maybe they did retire the option

Comment: The option was retired for a while (when these comments were made) when Fallen London had a mobile app. It has since returned.